# Induced edver-free graphs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

A graph of order $3$ in which there is exactly one edge we will call *edver* (**ed**ge + **ver**tex).
It is quite easy to prove the following statement.

> For a finite simple graph $G$ the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $G$ is an induced edver-free graph.
> 2. Any two distinct maximal independent sets of $G$ are disjoint.
> 3. $G$ is a complete $k$-partite graph for some $k\geq0$.
> 4. $G$ is an intersection graph of lines in the plane.

Actually my question is about this statement. Has a similar statement been discussed in the literature?
"Edver" is my term perhaps not a good one.
Is there another name for a graph of order three with exactly one edge?

Comment: An edver-free graph is just the complement of a $P_3$-free graph, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. I hadn't realized that one could look for $P_3$-free graphs, though I understood that.

Comment: Anyway, in my humble opinion the term "edver-free" is obscure and ugly, while "$\overline P_3$-free" (or $\overline K_{1,2}$-free) is self-explanatory.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right, $\overline{P}_3$ looks much better. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you very much.

Comment: A reference you may be interested in...there is a famous proof of Turan's Theorem via "Zykov Symmetrization" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turán%27s_theorem#Zykov_Symmetrization
 The equivalence you noted is used to conclude that a maximal K_r free graph is a complete multipartite graph

Comment: @dbal thanks, I'll take a look.